# Calculating the normal vector of 2 boxes that collide

Tags: java, vector, physics, collision, normals

I have been working on my own physics engine just for fun in processing. For a calculation i need the normal of the two boxes that collide. I have come up with this piece of code

```
PVector calcNormal(Box A, Box B) {

  PVector n = new PVector(B.pos.x-A.pos.x,B.pos.y-A.pos.y);
  PVector normal = new PVector(0,0);


  float a_extent = (A.max.x - A.min.x) / 2;
  float b_extent = (B.max.x - B.min.x) / 2;


  float x_overlap = a_extent + b_extent - abs( n.x );


  if(x_overlap > 0) {

     a_extent = (A.max.y - A.min.y) / 2;
     b_extent = (B.max.y - B.min.y) / 2;


    float y_overlap = a_extent + b_extent - abs( n.y );


    if(y_overlap > 0)
    {

      if(x_overlap > y_overlap)
      {

        if(n.x < 0) {
          normal.set( -1, 0 );
        }
        else {
          normal.set( 1, 0 );
        }

      }
      else
      {
        if(n.y < 0) {
          normal.set( 0, -1 );
        }
        else{
          normal.set( 0, 1 );
        }
      }
    } 
  }
  return normal;
}
```

I found it on a website called making your own custom 2d physics engine. But after implementing this it does not work. It gives me a weird normal vector that does to correspond with what i would expect as a normal. for example when the right side is touching the left side it returns a normal of (0,-1). Is my code correct or do i do something that is not correct?

Comment: Are you trying to find the normal vector from the center of box A to the center of box B?

Comment: I am trying to get the normal of the colliding sides (if i am correct). I will link the article. The normal is at the end in the function called AABBvsAABB [link](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331)

Comment: The normal (0,-1) is the correct rebound direction, what's wrong with it? As long as the collisions are simple, that is if two boxes collide then the involved sides fully overlap, or they don't collide at all,  it's ok. If you want to handle more complex collisions it involves some linear algebra. I can help you, what are you trying to achieve exactly?